# Author and Book Verification System: Identifying Author-Book Relationships in SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, console-application

```
 public void SearchAuthor(string AuthorName, out bool authorFound)
        {
            authorFound = false;
            using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    sqlconn.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM RentedBooks WHERE Auth = @Author", sqlconn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", AuthorName);

                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        authorFound = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("Author: {0} | Title: {1} | Borrower: {2}", reader["Auth"], reader["Title"], reader["Borrower"]);
                    }

                    if (authorFound == false)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No Author Found");
                    }
                    else if (authorFound && !reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Author found with No Books(s) Attached To Him");
                    }

                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Want it to read and check if there are any author in the system(database SQL) or if there is does he have a book attached to him if there isnt then write "Author found with No Books(s) Attached To Him" or if there isnt a author in the database then write "No Author Found"

[image: SC For an Author with books in database]

[image: SC For An Author with no books in database]

[image: SC For An Unkown Author]

Comment: Stack overflow is meant to be a knowledge-sharing repository. We are here to help solve coding problems that are general enough to be helpful to others. This question is too specific to your use case.